# Hello I am new to C and I tried how to print a name nth times using recursion but dont know where is did mistake?

Tags: c, function, recursion

I am new to this plz can anyone help me to correct this program.
**This is a program to print the entered name nth times.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
char* call(int i, int n,char name[30]){
    if (i<=n)
    return char name[30] ;
}
int main() {
    int i, n;
    char name[30];
    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin); 
    printf("How many time do you want to print: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n",call(i,n,name[30]));
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is not a recursive funtion. also `printf("%s\n",call(i,n,name30]));`, here you are passing `name[30]` meaning charactor at index 30 only, not the whole string, which will give error indexoutofbound

Comment: The problem that I have with an exercise like this, is that this is a terrible example, because recursion is absolutely not needed.

Comment: Independent of the issues in the code "recursion vs. iteration" is a "standard problem" that has *enough* answers already. No need to *ask*; instead *search*.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a way to use loops but it costs memory on stack due to function calls. And always a recursive function have a condition to exit the calls, in the case is when the `i` reaches the value of `n`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void call(int i,char name[30]){
    if(i==0)
        return;
    printf("%s\n",name);
    call(i-1,name);
}
int main() {
    int n;
    char name[30];
    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin); 
    printf("How many time do you want to print: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    call(n,name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Parameter 'n` (or (`i`) is useless. (I wanted to improve the answer, but the edit queue is full once again). Also `++i` is nonsense if `i` isn't used again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do recursion, you don't want a `for` loop. The number of recursive calls represents the loop.

Try like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void call(int n, const char* name)
{
    if (n <= 0) return;
    if (n > 1) call(n-1 , name);
    printf("%s\n", name);
}

int main() 
{
    int n = 5;
    char name[30] = "Hello";
    call(n, name);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Usually you would implement iteration as tail recursion.

Comment: @U.Windl nah... doesn't matter for this